# List Box Dependent on two Combo Boxes VBA

Tags: vba, combobox, listbox, dependencies

I am attempting to make three list box columns dependent on my selection of the first two combo boxes.

Here is a screenshot of my current form:

[image]

I have tried doing Cases but this is only working with the two combo boxes themselves and will not say

Is there any way of doing this?

Currently I have this:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

With StateComboBox


    .AddItem "CO - Colorado"

End With
End Sub
____________________________________________________
Private Sub StateComboBox_Change()

Dim index As Long
index = StateComboBox.ListIndex

RoleComboBox.Clear

Select Case StateComboBox.Value
    Case Is = "CO - Colorado"
     With RoleComboBox
        .AddItem "District"
        .AddItem "School"
        .AddItem "Test Administrator"
    End With


End Select
End Sub
____________________________________________
Private Sub PermissionSetList_change()

If StateComboBox.Value = "CO - Colorado" And RoleComboBox.Value = "District" Then
Call ColoradoDPermissionSet
Call ColoradoDRemovePermissions
Call ColoradoDAddPermissions
End If

End Sub
____________________________________________
Sub ColoradoDPermissionSet()

With PermissionSetList

.AddItem "Administrator"
.AddItem "Correction Primary Window"
.AddItem "Documents - View"

End With
End Sub
________________________________________________________
Sub ColoradoDRemovePermissions()

With RemoveList

.AddItem "Corrections - Primary"
.AddItem "Student Transfer Form"

End With
End Sub
_________________________________________________
Sub ColoradoDAddPermissions()

With AddList

.AddItem "Test Tickets - End Incomplete Test"
.AddItem "Test Tickets - Invalidate"
.AddItem "Test Tickets - Regenerate"

End With
End Sub
```

I have placed in the IF statement in the code and when I choose CO - Colorado and District, the list boxes will not populate. I would like to have it where when I select the State and Role it will populate specific values in the List Boxes and when I change the State and/or Role it will give a different set of "Permissions" which is why I was putting the lists inside of a sub and calling them.

Comment: Please clarify your question more.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ... What do you exactly want to do in the third list box?

Comment: Remove the `Call` keyword, it's useless. Then remove the commas, they're not legal. And add `End If` to close your `If` block.

Comment: Do you get errors?  Please add them... 'This is not working' is not very helpful...  Perhaps you need to access the TEXT (Or SelectedItem) property of the Listboxes in your IF statement

Comment: Where are you putting your IF statement?  ie When does it get called, and when do you WANT it to be called?

Comment: Added the If statement to the Code and when I select Colorado and District it still leaves the List Boxes blank

Answer (score 0):

I have figured this out, instead of an If statement alone I did the following and it populated how I wanted it to:

```
Private Sub RoleComboBox_Change()

Dim index As Long
index = RoleComboBox.ListIndex

PermissionSetList.Clear
RemoveList.Clear
AddList.Clear

If StateComboBox.Value = "CO - Colorado" Then
  Select Case RoleComboBox.Value
    Case Is = "District"
      With PermissionSetList
        Call ColoradoDPermissionSet
        Call ColoradoDRemovePermissions
        Call ColoradoDAddPermissions
      End With
 End Select
End If
End Sub
```

---

This is scalable so adding more If's can allow more for more selections to be made:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSpMX.png

```
Private Sub RoleComboBox_Change()

Dim index As Long
index = RoleComboBox.ListIndex

PermissionSetList.Clear
RemoveList.Clear
AddList.Clear

If StateComboBox.Value = "AL - Alabama" Then
With PermissionSetList
 Select Case RoleComboBox.Value

 Case Is = "District"
     Call WIDADPermissionSet
     Call AlabamaDRemovePermissions
     Call AlabamaDAddPermissions

  Case Is = "School"
     Call AlabamaSPermissionSet
     Call AlabamaSRemovePermissions
      Call AlabamaSAddPermissions

 Case Is = "Test Administrator"
     Call WIDATPermissionSet
     Call WIDATRemovePermissions
     Call WIDATAddPermissions
   End Select
 End With
End If

If StateComboBox.Value = "CO - Colorado" Then
  With PermissionSetList
    Select Case RoleComboBox.Value

   Case Is = "District"
       Call WIDADPermissionSet
       Call ColoradoDRemovePermissions
       Call ColoradoDAddPermissions

   Case Is = "School"
       Call ColoradoSPermissionSet
       Call ColoradoSRemovePermissions
       Call ColoradoSAddPermissions

   Case Is = "Test Administrator"
       Call WIDATPermissionSet
       Call WIDATRemovePermissions
       Call WIDATAddPermissions
    End Select
  End With
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: If it meets your needs. How scalable is it when you have multiple states and roles?

Comment: Updated to include more, as well as an image with the form right now. With this I am able to use the top combo box to add more variety and scale it out to different Projects.

Comment: The above is what i was worried about. It is not scalable in the way i was thinking as you are re-using over and over sections of code. It will slow your application and make debugging your code a nightmare.

Comment: Read into some of the SOLID principles of Object Oriented Design especially the idea of the SRP – Single Responsibility Principle.  Also, for the example above, you only need the first IF StateComboBox.Value = "AL - Alabama"  and then inside have the various Case statements.

Comment: With the change of removing the IF's it still works. In this case, there will be about 39 states with 3 roles each so it's not a whole ton. I have made a call tracker form which I use the same concept of populating a combo box depending on the other except using a call to pull down a list of hundreds of values and there is no slowdown of the application. Is there a way to condense this further?

Comment: I don't know enough about the other objects/subs you are working with but i would expect If  StateComboBox.Value = "AL - Alabama"  With PermissionSetList Select Case RoleComboBox.Value
Case  "District"  ...do stuff, Case "School"... do stuff......etc End Select   End With End If. Possibly i would have the With statement outside of the If. That is for starters.

Comment: ^^^ This is not exact code but the shell structure and only for what you have written above. Not how an OOP approach would go about it but that is probably for a different question!

Comment: This worked flawlessly! updated the code, this will make it a lot cleaner and easier to control. I'll also be putting Comments on things of course to make it easier to read.

Comment: you can contract Case Is = "District" to Case "District" etc..... and as Mat'sMug mentioned, you should be able to drop the obsolete Call references.

Comment: And it looks like, still not OOP way, the With PermissionSetList should be able to go outside of all the IF statements as  With PermissionSetList ....all If statements e.g. Alabama, Colorado..... End With i.e. you only write With End With once on the outside.